# Puppet and agent server with same host name but different private keys

Tags: amazon-ec2, puppet

I am trying to use puppet as follows in Amazon AWS:

I deploy an instance which has hostname "server.example.com", which launches the puppet agent on boot and gets an initial software payload.

I then terminate that instance.

I then re-launch a new instance with the same hostname, which generates a new private key and csr for that instance with the same hostname "server.example.com"

This time, the puppet agent update fails, because the private key on the new instance, doesn't match the key for that hostname on the puppet master.

How do I overcome this?

Comment: `I then terminate that instance.` - Make cleaning up the cert on master part of your termination process.   On master issue  `puppet cert --clean certname`

Comment: Hmmm, is there any way to remove the cert verification process? All these instances are in a private VPC.

Comment: @GarrethMcDaid: You can enable autosigning (https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/ssl_autosign.html) but I don't think it will clean certs. And it's generally not a great idea. Maybe a masterless setup is better for your setup.

Comment: Autosigning is already enabled. The issue here is mismatch between the private key and cert on the master.

Answer (score 0):

puppet uses a box's fqdn to work.   so no, to my knowledge, you cant have two clients with the same fqdn. you first have to clean cert as Zoredache mentions in comments. there is a way to bypass puppet master authorization, and sign and allow any incoming request (i forgot directive for this in puppetmaster in conf), but even if you do this, it wont work if theres an existing signed server cert, and a new request comes in with that same fqdn.  btw, i strongly recommend against having puppetmaster sign any incoming fqdn. someone could request to your puppetmaster and thus pull things they should not.  i guess irrelevant if vpc/privatelan, but i still wouldnt do it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this, but it should only be used in development environments.

**Do not use this in any environment where security is a requirement.**

You can open up the puppet REST api to allow agents revoke and delete certificates. Add the following to the auth.conf on your puppet master

```
path /certificate_status
auth any
method find, save, destroy
allow *
```

Restart the puppetmaster service when you have made this change

```
sudo service puppetmaster restart
```

When you are launching your instance, you can then pass user data which will be run as a script when the instance boots (the script will run as root)

```
#!/bin/bash

curl -k -X PUT -H "Content-Type: text/pson" --data '{"desired_state":"revoked"}'     https://puppet:8140/production/certificate_status/$HOSTNAME

curl -k -X DELETE -H "Accept: pson"  https://puppet:8140/production/certificate_status/$HOSTNAME

rm -Rf /var/lib/puppet/ssl/*

puppet agent -t
```

This will revoke the agent cert on the master, remove it, remove the cert on the agent and re-generate a new one.

Save this file locally and then pass it to the Amazon EC2 API when launching an new instance

```
aws ec2 run-instances <snip> --user-data file://./pclean.sh
```

Where pclean.sh is the name of the locally saved script file, and it is saved in the same directory as your working directory (otherwise include the absolute path).

With this in place, each time you launch a new instance, regardless of its *initial* hostname, it will revoke any existing cert that has the same hostname, and generate a new one.

Obviously, if you are launching hundreds of instances at the same time, you may have concurrency issues, and some other solution will be required.

Answer (score 0):

Another proposed solution here:

https://gist.github.com/ahpook/1182243

Use a generic certificate for all agents connecting to the puppet master